# Visualize the Julia Type Tree

Tags: julia

Is there a convenient way to visualize the Julia type tree? I know I can write a function for that...

```
function ttree(t::Type, indent = "    ")
    println(string(indent, t))
    indent *= "    "
    for st in subtypes(t)
        ttree(st, indent)
    end
end

ttree(Integer)

    Integer
        Bool
        Signed
            BigInt
            Int128
            Int16
            Int32
            Int64
            Int8
        Unsigned
            UInt128
            UInt16
            UInt32
            UInt64
            UInt8
```

...but Julia's strong pronunciation of multiple dispatch makes me feel like there must be some cool built-in function for that, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `GraphRecipes`:

```
using GraphRecipes, Plots
plot(Integer, method=:tree, fontsize=10, nodeshape=:rect)
```

[image]

Here is an ASCII approach

```
using AbstractTrees
AbstractTrees.children(d::DataType) = subtypes(d)
```

And here it is in action

```
julia> print_tree(Integer)
Integer
├─ Bool
├─ Signed
│  ├─ BigInt
│  ├─ Int128
│  ├─ Int16
│  ├─ Int32
│  ├─ Int64
│  └─ Int8
└─ Unsigned
   ├─ UInt128
   ├─ UInt16
   ├─ UInt32
   ├─ UInt64
   └─ UInt8
```

Comment: This is really good. Thank you. The only caveat here: while this is could for including it in some document, it seems like a bit of overkill for quickly checking some type.

Comment: OK - I added this for you

Comment: Awesome. That's what I was looking for. I wish it was in base, but I guess as the great philosopher Mig Jagger said "you can't always get what you want".

Answer (score 1):

[Term.jl](https://github.com/FedeClaudi/Term.jl/) provides a `typestree` function that produces a beautiful tree of types:

[image: Term.typestree output, a coloured tree of types]

But it only seems to go upwards i.e. the *supertype* hierarchy of a given type. An option to dig down to get lower level subtypes doesn't (as of Term v1.0.4) seem to exist. It does print out  the immediate subtypes of a type, just not the levels down from those.
[image: typestree output for Integer type]